# After disallow browser page's context menu, how to display it again using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, contextmenu

For example, I've codes below:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Running some codes here...
  // Now I wanna display the context menu. How can I do?
}, true;
```

After disallow browser page's context menu, how to display it again using JavaScript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return true;` will do the opposite.

Ex:

```
if (...) {
    e.preventDefault();

} else {
    return true;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/TXVt6/1/

Comment: @wei Don't forget to accept the answer if this answers your question.

Comment: Sorry. casablanca's answer is right. And your codes can't run successfully. And also `return true;` and `return false;` both don't work in W3C standard browser. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @wei what browser is return true not working for you. my answer demonstrates how you can reactivate by using return true.

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault` prevents the menu from happening.  Just skip this call if you want the default action (which is to pop up the menu).